# Command not found error for particular line endings in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu

I have the below piece of code in one of my scripts. Although the script works fine and produces the expected output, I get the below errors each time:

callHomeProperties.sh: line 154: 1: command not found
callHomeProperties.sh: line 160: 1: command not found

```
148    if [[ "$OS_VERSION_DB" = "$OS_VERSION_FILE" && "$DB_DETAILS_DB" = "$DB_DETAILS_FILE" && "$APP_SERVER_DB" = "$APP_SERVER_FILE" && "$AAOP_VERSION_DB" = "$AAOP_VERSION_FILE" && "$VMWARE_DB"         = "$VMWARE_FILE" ]]; then
149        echo "same entry for the customer updating the time stamp and the data date"
150        `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog <<endSQL
151        connect call_home/call_home@$ORASVC
152        update call_home_headers set LAST_UPDATED_DATE = sysdate where (CUSTOMER_NAME='$CUSTOMER_NAME_FILE' and OS_VERSION='$OS_VERSION_DB' and DB_DETAILS='$DB_DETAILS_DB' and APP_SERVER='$A        PP_SERVER_DB' and AAOP_VERSION='$AAOP_VERSION_DB' and VMWARE='$VMWARE_DB');
153        exit
154        endSQL`
155       `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog <<endSQL
156        connect call_home/call_home@$ORASVC
157        update call_home_headers set DATA_DATE = TO_DATE('$DATA_DATE_FILE','yyyy/MM/dd HH/MI/SS') where (CUSTOMER_NAME='$CUSTOMER_NAME_FILE' and OS_VERSION='$OS_VERSION_DB' and DB_DETAILS='$        DB_DETAILS_DB' and APP_SERVER='$APP_SERVER_DB' and AAOP_VERSION='$AAOP_VERSION_DB' and VMWARE='$VMWARE_DB');
158
159        exit
160        endSQL`
161
```

Can anyone please help out here. I have already tried dos2unix assuming that its a problem because of line endings, but that didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: why does the command need to be in backticks?

Comment: I used that assuming that the entire block needs to be run as a command, removing the backticks removed the error also. Thanks

Comment: If you want to group commands, use `{}`.  In this case, the heredoc is all you need. The backticks cause the shell to execute the command and store the output.  The way you are using them, it then tries to evaluate that output as a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your `sqlplus` commands are in backquotes, so the shell will try to execute the output of the command.  I'm guessing the output isn't valid shell, and that's why it's complaining.

The simple fix is to remove the backquotes:

```
"$ORACLE_HOME"/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog <<endSQL
connect call_home/call_home@$ORASVC
update call_home_headers set LAST_UPDATED_DATE = sysdate where (...);
endSQL
```

It may be a good idea to sanitise `$ORASVC` and other variables you use, unless they come from trusted sources (i.e. not user input) and don't contain anything meaningful to SQL, otherwise you have a pile of SQL-injection vulnerabilities waiting to be exploited.